# run django in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a simple example of Django app running in docker container.

using this image https://hub.docker.com/_/django/
just for simplicity. Don't tell me please that i shouldn't use it in production :) app is very simple and i'm ok with using very basic Django server.

So, **the problem is** i'm always getting this **error** when trying to run the container image

```
C:\Users\slipo\PycharmProjects\simple_blog>docker run -p 8000:8000 my-blog
python: can't open file './manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

however, `./manage.py` and `mysite.settings.prod` both definitely existing in container.

**container creation log**  showing the file exists:

```
Step 7 : RUN ls -a
 ---> Running in 932ed2ad3e4c
.
..
.idea
Dockerfile
blog
manage.py
mysite
requirements.txt
templates
 ---> e7f938c1cbf2
Removing intermediate container 932ed2ad3e4c
Step 8 : CMD python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod
 ---> Running in f99bcafbc269
 ---> aca534e9ccb6
Removing intermediate container f99bcafbc269
Successfully built aca534e9ccb6
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM django

EXPOSE 8000

ADD . /simple_blog
WORKDIR /simple_blog

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install django-tinymce

RUN ls -a

CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod" ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `CMD [ "python", "/simple_blog/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod" ]`

Comment: Try `CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--settings=mysite.settings.prod" ]`

Comment: CMD has 3 syntaxes, check the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Also, `CMD python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod` will be valid, it means `sh -c` of  the CMD, the shell form of the CMD is `CMD executable param1 param2` see https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

Comment: Don't use relative paths.   Fixed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> can't open file './manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysite.settings.prod'

This is telling you that it is treating that entire string as a single filename.

I assume something like this works:

```
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--settings=mysite.settings.prod" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute this code.

```
CMD [ "python", "../manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 --settings=my_site.settings.prd"
```

Comment: you have typo `--settings=mysite.settings.prod` here. But thats not an issue anyway. just gives the same error.